# Include records are between filter dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table where is a set of records like this

> TimeStart             TimeEnd                 StoodType
>
> 2017-06-26 07:50:49.000   2017-06-26 11:33:13.000 95
>
> 2017-06-26 11:33:42.000   2017-06-26 11:35:07.000 90
>
> 2017-06-26 11:59:13.000   2017-06-26 12:16:33.000 94
>
> 2017-06-26 12:18:07.000   2017-06-26 12:21:38.000 94
>
> 2017-06-26 12:27:22.000   2017-06-26 12:29:51.000 94
>
> 2017-06-26 13:06:21.000   2017-06-26 13:08:19.000 90

I need to select records which are inside of 8:00 and 20:00
like

> 2017-06-26 07:50:49.000   2017-06-26 11:33:13.000 95

I try this SQL

```
declare @StartTime datetime
declare @EndTime datetime

set @StartTime = '20170626 8:00'
set @EndTime = '20170626 20:00'

SELECT   TimeStart, TimeEnd, StoodType  FROM  dbo.WDT
    WHERE TimeStart BETWEEN  @StartTime AND @EndTime
```

but it does not help

Any clue?

Comment: Where do you define `@StartTime` and `@EndTime` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Pls check updated question. Thank you!

Comment: Your query [works completely OK for me in this demo](http://rextester.com/RGXIY71355).  Maybe you have some other problems going on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hmmm But I need  include `2017-06-26 07:50:49.000 2017-06-26 11:33:13.000 95`  where is StartTume 7:50 is less than filter 8:00.

Comment: Do you know how `BETWEEN` works?  `07:50 am` is _not_ in between `8 am` and `8 pm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found correct solution. Thanks to **Stackoverflow**!

```
declare @StartTime datetime;
declare @EndTime datetime;

set @StartTime = '20170626 8:00';
set @EndTime = '20170626 20:00';       

SELECT (CASE   
      WHEN TimeStart < @StartTime THEN  @StartTime
     ELSE TimeStart
  END
  ) AS CorrectedTimeStart, (CASE   
      WHEN TimeEnd > @EndTime THEN  @EndTime
     ELSE TimeEnd
  END) AS CorrectedTimeEnd, 
  TimeStart, TimeEnd
     FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT TimeStart, TimeEnd FROM WDT WHERE TimeStart BETWEEN  @StartTime AND @EndTime
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT TimeStart, TimeEnd FROM WDT WHERE TimeEnd BETWEEN  @StartTime AND @EndTime
  ) A
```

[image]

Comment: why do you have to select a row which starts before your filter (StartTime) but not rows which end after your second filter (EndTime)?

Answer (score 0):

As you updated your information. It seems you want all sets which start, end or totally overlap the timeband 8am till 8pm.
If you don't need rows which completely overlap the 8am/8pm timeband, just remove the last two lines.

```
SELECT TimeStart, 
       TimeEnd, 
       StoodType  
  FROM dbo.WDT
    WHERE (     TimeStart BETWEEN  @StartTime AND @EndTime  -- Sets which start in your timeband
             OR TimeEnd   BETWEEN  @StartTime AND @EndTime) -- Sets which end in your timeband
        OR (    TimeStart < @StartTime   -- Sets which totally overlap your timeband
            AND TimeEnd > @EndTime
           )
;
```